# How to update some (but not all) fields of a record?

Tags: ocaml, record

I have a list named `diags` of type `Linol_lwt.Diagnostic.t list`
I want to update every element of this list and return another one.
Let's suppose that we have these modules:

```
module Diagnostic = struct
  type t =
    { range : Range.t
    ; severity : DiagnosticSeverity.t Json.Nullable_option.t
          [@default None] [@yojson_drop_default ( = )]
    ; code : Jsonrpc.Id.t Json.Nullable_option.t
          [@default None] [@yojson_drop_default ( = )]
    ; source : string Json.Nullable_option.t
          [@default None] [@yojson_drop_default ( = )]
    ; message : string
    ; tags : DiagnosticTag.t list Json.Nullable_option.t
          [@default None] [@yojson_drop_default ( = )]
    ; relatedInformation :
        DiagnosticRelatedInformation.t list Json.Nullable_option.t
          [@default None] [@yojson_drop_default ( = )]
    }
end
```

```
module Range = struct
  type t =
    { start : Position.t
    ; end_ : Position.t
    }
end
```

```
module Position = struct
  type t =
    { line : int
    ; character : int
    }
end
```

I want to update the field `range`, so I did this:

```
let diags2 = List.map ( fun (x: Linol_lwt.Diagnostic.t) ->

                            let ls = x.range.start in
                            let le = x.range.end_ in
                            {
                              Linol_lwt.Diagnostic.range =
                                {
                                  start = { ls with line = ls.line + 1 };
                                  end_ = { le with line = le.line + 1 }
                                }
                            }
                   ) diags in
```

But it says that there is an error with this message:

```
Some record fields are undefined: severity code source message tags relatedInformation
```

Answer (score 1):

As you mostly want to return the input value `x` with just the `range` field updated, you can use:

`{ x with range = ... }`

Or in place in your snippet above:

```
let diags2 = List.map ( fun (x: Linol_lwt.Diagnostic.t) ->

                            let ls = x.range.start in
                            let le = x.range.end_ in
                            { x with
                              Linol_lwt.Diagnostic.range =
                                {
                                  start = { ls with line = ls.line + 1 };
                                  end_ = { le with line = le.line + 1 }
                                }
                            }
                   ) diags in
```

To update multiple fields at once, use

`{ x with range = ...; field2 = ... }`

More detail here: https://dev.realworldocaml.org/records.html#scrollNav-4